# How do I redirect history to a file?

Tags: command-line

Is it possible to put the output of a command into a file? I tried doing a

`echo history > history.txt`

But it put the text *history* instead into that file.

Comment: This puts the output of the command `echo` into history.txt, which is exactly what you are asking how to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just do `history > history.txt` without the echo. That should do it. When you do echo history, you are telling unix to print history to screen rather then execute it, which is why `echo history > history.txt` only contains the word history.

Comment: It's always the simple ones I tend to fail in. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The example as given is probably unnecessary unless you want *unwritten* history from the current session. Your ~/.bash_history or similar file will already have your history from past sessions saved.

You can append the current session's history with `history -w`. Then your ~/.bash_history file will be up-to-date, including items from the current session.